# Get text and value from label

Tags: jquery

Trying to pull the text from a label on the page but it's not working.  The id is right that is in the contains.

```
     var modelid = $("label:contains('singleModelText')").text();
```

Comment: show some html so we can see if there is an error in your selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get the element by ID try:

```
var modelid = $('label[id*="singleModelText"]').text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be something like

```
var modelid = $('label[id*="singleModelText"]').text();
```

See here for more on the "attribute contains selector":

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

If `$("label:contains('singleModelText')").length == 0` then your selector is **not** right.

Answer (score 0):

`:contains()` is a [selector that searches an element for a string](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), returning elements that have that text. The way I interpret your question is you have a document like this:

```
<label>I want this text <input id="singleModelText" /></label>
```

If that's not the case feel free to stop here, if that is the case however you want something like this:

```
$("#singleModelText").parent("label").text();
```